# NDSolve emitting error message NDSolve::ndnum

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve this system

```
equn1 = ψ'[x] == - Elec[x]
equn2 = Elec'[x] == - ((di/ a)^2)[(Exp[ψ[x]] - (x/(xoi*Sqrt[-ψ[x]])))]
```

For that I am using `NDSolve` as given below.

```
di = 0.001; a = 0.01; xoi = (1/0.15); 
ans1 =  
  NDSolve[{
     ψ'[x] == - Elec[x], 
     Elec'[x] == - ((di/ a)^2)[(Exp[ψ[x]] - (x/(xoi*Sqrt[-ψ[x]])))],
     ψ[ 1.3] == -1.69, Elec[1.3] == 2.6}, 
     {ψ[x], Elec[x]}, {x, 1.3, 2.7}]
```

But for any initial value of `x` an error is encountered

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 1.3`. >>

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63280/numerical-solution-to-two-non-linear-coupled-differential-equations

Answer (score 2):

You had syntax errors (used `[]` instead of `()`) (also why define equations and not using them in the call?)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
eq1 = ψ'[x] == -elec[x];
di = 0.001; a = 0.01; xoi = (1/0.15);
eq2 = elec'[x] == -((di/a)^2) (Exp[ψ[x]] - (x/(xoi*Sqrt[-ψ[x]])));
NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, ψ[1.3] == -1.69, elec[1.3] == 2.6}, {ψ[x], elec[x]}, {x, 1.3, 2.7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]